# Is this a correct formulation of a linear programming problem?

Tags: linear-programming

I apologise as English is not my first language so sometimes I get stuck on problems like these as it can confuse easily.

> Show & Sell can advertise its products on local radio and television
>   (TV). The advertising budget is limited to £10,000 a month. Each
>   minute of radio advertising costs £15 and each minute of TV
>   commercials £300. Show & Sell likes to advertise on radio at least
>   twice as much as on TV. In the meantime, it is not practical to use
>   more than 400 minutes of radio advertising a month. From past
>   experience, advertising on TV is estimated to be 25 times as effective
>   as on radio. Determine the optimum allocation of the budget to radio
>   and TV advertising. Model this problem as a linear programming
>   problem.

Here is what I did:

Let $T$ be the number of minutes of TV advertising and $R$ be the number of radio minutes advertising then we have:

Max:$~25R+T\\s.t.\\15R+300T \leq 10000\\2T\leq R\\R \leq 400
\\R,T \geq0$

Is this even near being correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost correct. But the objective function has to be $$\texttt{Max} \ \ R+25T$$

The output per one minute advertising on television is 25 times the output per minute advertising on radio.